# SQL - Setting Value From Hierarchical Children

Tags: sql, hierarchical-data

I am writing an application which gets task data from a project planning `MS SQL` table (let's call the table `tasks`). For simplicity the table fields can be thought of as follows:

`task_id, parent_id, name, start_date, end_date`

All parent tasks have `NULL` as start and end dates. Only the children (with no children of their own) have a start and end date.

I want to get the tasks data and in the process set the start date of each parent based upon the earliest start date of all the parent's children and recursive grandchildren and set the end date to be the latest end date of all the children and recursive grandchildren. Is this possible please?

Comment: If you add some sample data and result that you want to see you will get help more quiqly

Comment: Would you want to do that calculation only for parent tasks (i.e. those with a null parent_id) or all tasks?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume from your question that you use `Sql Server`. I think this is what you want. It is done with recursive common table expression. It begins with leaf children and goes up to top most parents:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(id INT, pid INT, sd DATE, ed DATE)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(2, 1, NULL, NULL),
(3, 2, '20150201', '20150215'),
(4, 2, '20150101', '20150201'),
(5, 1, NULL, NULL),
(6, 5, '20150301', '20150401'),
(7, 1, NULL, NULL),
(8, 7, NULL, NULL),
(9, 8, '20140101', '20141230'),
(10, 8, '20140102', '20141231')

;WITH cte AS(
SELECT * FROM @t WHERE sd IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT t.id, t.pid, c.sd, c.ed FROM @t t
JOIN cte c ON c.pid = t.id
)

SELECT id, pid, MIN(sd) AS sd, MAX(ed) AS ed 
FROM cte
GROUP BY id, pid
ORDER BY id
```

Output:

```
id  pid   sd            ed
1   NULL  2014-01-01    2015-04-01
2   1     2015-01-01    2015-02-15
3   2     2015-02-01    2015-02-15
4   2     2015-01-01    2015-02-01
5   1     2015-03-01    2015-04-01
6   5     2015-03-01    2015-04-01
7   1     2014-01-01    2014-12-31
8   7     2014-01-01    2014-12-31
9   8     2014-01-01    2014-12-30
10  8     2014-01-02    2014-12-31
```

Comment: Giorgi you are spot on! Thank you. On further research last night I came upon recursive common table expressions, I have never heard of them before. I found them confusing to get to grips with but seeing your answer based upon a simple scenario I now understand how they work. You never stop learning.